# AWS lambda nodejs function without using accessKeyId and secretAccessKey?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Working on a function, I've used to `aws-sdk`, as suggested. Which requires accessKeyId and secretAccessKey.

I'm wondering, since I assigned a role to the function and that role has a set of permissions, is there a way to use the permission of the role to download/upload from/to a bucket, and there by not putting the credentials in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set appropriate role to the AWS lambda with necessary access, then you don't need any accessKey and secretKey.

Comment: Indeed, weird that I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the aws documentation page
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/nodejs-write-lambda-function-example.html

**Configuring the SDK**

Here is the portion of the Lambda function that configures the SDK. The credentials are not provided in the code because they are supplied to a Lambda function through the required IAM execution role.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});
```

Bacisally you shouldn't need to specify the access key and secret when providing IAM execution role